# Understand proof: Set of bilinear forms is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, group-isomorphism, bilinear-form, vector-space-isomorphism

I don't understand the proof of the following problem:

Problem: Prove that the set S of all bilinear forms on a vector space V (call them Bil(V )) has the structure of a vector space.

Here's the proof:

"The natural addition and scalar multiplication on bilinear forms correspond with the addition and scalar multiplication of n × n matrices. We know that forms a vector space."

My question 1: Here the "natural addition and scalar multiplication" were defined elsewhere and I could understand them, what I **don't** understand is why the fact that these operations correspond to analogous operations of n × n matrices proves S is also a vector space.

My question 2: Also, does that mean if a set V and a vector space W are isomorphic (let $\Phi$ be an isomorphism between them) and V has the operations "addition $\star$" and "scalar multiplication $\lozenge$" such that $\Phi (a\star b)=\Phi(a)+\Phi(b)$ and $\Phi (\lambda \lozenge a)=\lambda \cdot \Phi(a)$, where + and $\cdot$ are addition and scalar multiplication on W,
then V is also a vector space?

Comment: The answer to question 1 is question 2 and the answer to question 2 is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure (in question 2, better call $\Phi$ a bijection than an isomorphism. It will become an isomorphism afterwards, once $V$ is given the appropriate structure of vector space) (in question 1, $V$ is supposed to be $n$-dimensional and a basis is chosen, to construct $\Phi$).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit misguided to talk about a *set* being a vector space or not.
A vector space, strictly speaking, is a set **together with the two vector space operations**.

This means that to ask if a set is a vector space, you first have to *define* which two operations you want to use as the vector space operations, otherwise the question is meaningless.

It is similarly meaningless to speak of a set and a vector space being isomorphic, but if you have a *bijection* $\Phi$ from a set $S$ to a vector space $V$ and define operations $\star, \lozenge$ by
$$
a \star b := \Phi^{-1}(\Phi(a) + \Phi(b)), \\
\lambda \lozenge a := \Phi^{-1}(\lambda \cdot \Phi(a)),
$$
then your set $S$ with these operations will be a vector space.
Basically, what that's doing is just "relabling" the elements of $V$ using the set $S$, which works since there is a one-to-one correspondence from elements of $V$ to elements of $S$ (given by $\Phi$).